# How to run Jupyter Notebook project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Complete noob here wanting to know on how to run prooject that is created in Jupyter Notebook ([here](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow)) in Eclipse IDE. Btw, I am working on virtual environtment if that makes differences.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open your running ipython notebook and go to `File-> Download as-> Python File`.

Now you can just import it like regular python file and run it.